# Within SQL Server Mgmt Studio, is it possible to query against 'SQL Server Agent > Jobs'

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

Within SQL Server Mgmt Studio, is it possible to query against 'SQL Server Agent > Jobs' and successfully transfer the results produced for 'failed Jobs within a 24hr period' to something like Excel?

Comment: Take a peek at http://www.sqlmatters.com/Articles/Checking%20the%20status%20of%20SQL%20Server%20Agent%20jobs.aspx

Comment: I can't get this to wor sorry, I get the same code - `Msg 208, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 Invalid object name 'sysjobhistory'.'` - but I can't solve it the same way as below. Do you know of the best way to get this data in an Excel document, not just .CSV or .TXT, but a way of running this query each time, so it updates daily as and when? I'm not fussed on how the data is dislayed, be it a website/excel document etc..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I usually create a report that uses a similar query to the one below to find all the jobs that failed and what steps failed.  You can filter it for the job you want as well. All the information is in the msdb database.

```
SELECT j.name JobName,h.step_name StepName, 
CONVERT(CHAR(10), CAST(STR(h.run_date,8, 0) AS dateTIME), 111) RunDate, 
STUFF(STUFF(RIGHT('000000' + CAST ( h.run_time AS VARCHAR(6 ) ) ,6),5,0,':'),3,0,':') RunTime, 
h.run_duration StepDuration,
case h.run_status when 0 then 'failed'
when 1 then 'Succeded' 
when 2 then 'Retry' 
when 3 then 'Cancelled' 
when 4 then 'In Progress' 
end as ExecutionStatus, 
h.message MessageGenerated
FROM sysjobhistory h inner join sysjobs j
ON j.job_id = h.job_id
where h.run_status = 0 and CONVERT(varchar(8),h.run_date,112) = CONVERT(varchar(8),GetDate(),112)
```

Comment: I get the code `Msg 208, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Invalid object name 'sysjobhistory'.'`

Comment: I've used my original code here [LINK](http://pastebin.com/raw/8ZB6MWKi). Thank you, this has really helped!

Comment: The results are duplicated, the only difference between the two is that the **Job Step Name** on each duplicate states **(Job Outcome)** for all and the **Message Generated** shows as **Executed as..** for one, and **Job failed..** for the other. Which I don't mind. Would probably just want the duplicate to show the same **Job Step Name** not **(Job Outcome)**. I don't suppose you know of a way?

Comment: The Job History is done by Job Step Name.  You can modify the query if you want to group on j.Name and just do a max of the Run Date but then you will not get all the messages for the failed jobs. @JChutey

Comment: Thank you @Alwaysariyana you've been a massive help, finally have my two Queries all sorted. Now to work these into Excel or something else to display the results!